# resizableImageWithCapInsets with imageWithRenderingMode

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to colour my image with my tint colour. The code below works fine as long as the image view does not exceed a height of 61 or a width of 96. Does anyone know what is going on?

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bubble_mask_r.png"];
myImage = [myImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 26, 11)];
myImage = [myImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

self.imageView1.image = myImage;
self.imageView2.image = myImage;
```

[image]

Source Image 78x64px:

[image]

Comment: Has your source image been sliced in assets catalog?

Comment: No, I am not using an asset catalog.

Comment: I have the same issue on iOS 7.0. Works well on iOS 7.1

Comment: Yes, indeed, it has since been fixed.